# Adding spinner to ActionBar in Fragment(Not Navigation Listener)

Tags: android-actionbar

I want to display spinner in action bar(not in activity,in Fragment).for that i did below things

**Step-1** (spinnermenu.xml)

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuSort"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/spinner"/>
</menu>`
```

**Step-2** (spinner.xml)

```
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**step-3** (Code)

```
public class All extends Fragment{

ArrayList<String> spinnerlist;
ArrayAdapter<String> spinneradapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.spinnermenu, menu);
     spinnerlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    spinnerlist.add("Items1");
    spinnerlist.add("Items2");
     spinneradapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerlist);

     Spinner s = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.menuSort).getActionView();
            s.setAdapter(spinneradapter);            
     super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
}
```

I am getting error in this line

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

and Null exception in this line

```
s.setAdapter(spinneradapter);
```

Could any one tell me how to rectify this error?

****PS*** : Is there any way to do the same?*